# Why does the command, alert($(this).attr("id")); return "undefined"?

Tags: jquery

Why does the command

```
alert($(this).attr("id"));
```

return "undefined"? I'm using it in ASP NET and Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: Could you show the surrounding code and markup?

Comment: Without the markup even the Lord (read Jon Skeet) can't help you :) Just copy the relevant HTML along with the rest of your javascript and we'll be on it. cheers

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

> If we try to get the value of an attribute that has not been set, the .attr() method returns undefined.

Maybe some informations are missing? ^^

Answer (score 1):

Either `this` does not have an ID, or it's not the element you think it is.

Answer (score -5):

I think 'this' is referring to the alert box which I am guessing does not have an attribute called id.

Comment: I think my sarcasm might have been lost

Comment: doh- the id is the attribute of 'this' which is the element the alert box is being called on. If the alerts was being call onclick then the id would be the element that was being clicked on.